# JNDI, name service and local files system

Tags: java, jndi

I am trying to clear my doubts on JNDI by writing some examples, by searching on the net. I came across the following link (tutorial from oracle on this topic)

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/getStarted/examples/naming.html
```

In this link, it says:

> "This example shows you how to write a program that looks up an object whose name is passed in as a command-line argument. It uses a service provider for the file system."

As per my understanding JNDI standardizes how we access/lookup for naming and directory services objects, something similar below:

Java app ---"uses JNDI API" --> to access directory/naming service's objects.

Now, in the example, it is says "look up of object in file system". So is file system a "naming service" ?

Are these "services" a program/software which is accessible via SPI? what role does SPI play here?

I might be incorrect, are SPI's implementation of "JNDI API"? (like JDBC drivers implement JDBC API's).

I am confused even though i have gone through online material.

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is file system a "naming service" ?

The file system provider is a JNDI SPI that uses the file system instead of a real naming service. It's a toy, not for serious use. Just a proof of concept.

> Are these "services" a program/software which is accessible via SPI?

Usually. For example, COSnaming, LDAP, RMI Registry.

> what role does SPI play here?

It's the implementation of a JNDI for a particular naming service.

> I might be incorrect, are SPI's implementation of "JNDI API"? (like JDBC drivers implement JDBC API's).

Sorta kinda, yes.